# Display PR curve on Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, display, tensorboard

I'm trying to to display a mAP or precision response curve using tensorflow and tensorboard. Currently I have tensorboard displaying my `accuracy`, `precision`, `f-score`, and `recall` for the training and testing by epoch, but am having problems getting the `pr_curve` to work.  I either get the error

> "TypeError:   input/Placeholder_1:0 must be of type dtype: 'bool'"

and if I change the float to a bool, I get the error

> "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You
>   must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/Placeholder_1' with
>   dtype float and shape [?,2]"

I've tried different things like moving the commands related to the pr_curve or using variables copies to pass as parameters with no benefit.  If I remark the `pf_curve` command out, I don't get an error, but I also don't get a curve.

Here is my code, the `pr_curve` command is line 109, or 110, depending on the error.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import pdb 

def make_bread():
    pdb.set_trace()
    return "I don't have time"

import numpy as np
import math, time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorboard import summary as summ_lib
import flags as f
import input, lenet5, evaluate

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
similar results every run)
tf.set_random_seed(1)
np.random.seed(10)

summaries = {'train': [], 'validate': [], 'test': []}

def main(unused_argv):
     train_dataset, validate_dataset, test_dataset = 
input.input(shuffle_files=False)
     info = tf.constant(
            ["Batch size = %s" % f.FLAGS.batch_size,
             "Epochs = %s" % f.FLAGS.num_epochs,
             "Learning rate = %s" % f.FLAGS.learning_rate,
             "Batch normalization = No",
             "Window size = %s" % f.FLAGS.window_size,
             "Shuffle Files = No",
             "CNN model = %s" % f.FLAGS.cnn_model,
             "Shuffle Samples = YES"]
      )
      with tf.name_scope('input'):
            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input.SAMPLE_DEPTH, 
input.SAMPLE_HEIGHT, input.SAMPLE_WIDTH])
            y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
            dropout_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

      with tf.name_scope('logits'):
            if f.FLAGS.cnn_model == "lenet5":
                  logits = lenet5.model_fn(sample_input = x, 
is_training=is_training, summaries=summaries)

      with tf.name_scope('loss'):
            cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y_, logits=logits)
            mean_cross_entropy_loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

            loss_summ = tf.summary.scalar('Mean_cross_entropy_loss', mean_cross_entropy_loss)
            summaries['train'].append(loss_summ)

      with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(f.FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(mean_cross_entropy_loss)

      with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
            preds = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
            correct_preds = tf.argmax(y_, 1)
            equal = tf.equal(preds, correct_preds)
            training_accuracy_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(equal, tf.float32))

summaries['train'].append(tf.summary.scalar('Training_Accuracy', training_accuracy_op))


      with tf.name_scope('Evaluation_Metrics'):
            tp_op = evaluate.tp(logits=logits, labels=y_)
            fp_op = evaluate.fp(logits=logits, labels=y_)
            tn_op = evaluate.tn(logits=logits, labels=y_)
            fn_op = evaluate.fn(logits=logits, labels=y_)

            tp_sum = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            tn_sum = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            fp_sum = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            fn_sum = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

            precision_op = evaluate.precision(tp=tp_sum, fp=fp_sum, tn=tn_sum, fn=fn_sum)
            accuracy_op = evaluate.accuracy(tp=tp_sum, fp=fp_sum, tn=tn_sum, fn=fn_sum)
            recall_op = evaluate.recall(tp=tp_sum, fp=fp_sum, tn=tn_sum, fn=fn_sum)
            fscore_op = evaluate.fscore(tp=tp_sum, fp=fp_sum, tn=tn_sum, fn=fn_sum)

            precision_summ = tf.summary.scalar('Precision', precision_op)
            accuracy_summ = tf.summary.scalar('Accuracy', accuracy_op)
            recall_summ = tf.summary.scalar('Recall', recall_op)
            fscore_summ = tf.summary.scalar('Fscore', fscore_op)

            summaries['validate'].append(accuracy_summ)
            summaries['validate'].append(precision_summ)
            summaries['validate'].append(recall_summ)
            summaries['validate'].append(fscore_summ)

            summaries['test'].append(accuracy_summ)
            summaries['test'].append(precision_summ)
            summaries['test'].append(recall_summ)
            summaries['test'].append(fscore_summ)

      print ("Saving graph to %s" % f.FLAGS.log_dir)
      mAP_summ = summ_lib.pr_curve(name='mAP',predictions=logits,labels=y_,num_thresholds=11)
      # OR THIS ONE mAP_summ = summ_lib.pr_curve(name='mAP',predictions=logits,labels=tf.cast(y_,tf.bool),num_thresholds=11)

      train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(f.FLAGS.log_dir + "/train")
      validate_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(f.FLAGS.log_dir + "/validate")
      test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(f.FLAGS.log_dir + "/test")
      train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())

      train_summaries = tf.summary.merge(summaries['train'])
      validate_summaries = tf.summary.merge(summaries['validate'])
      test_summaries = tf.summary.merge(summaries['test'])

      with tf.Session() as sess:
            train_writer.add_summary(sess.run(tf.summary.text("Information", info)))
            train_iter = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
            train_next_elem = train_iter.get_next()
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            global_step = 0
            display_freq = 10
            validate_freq = 50
            test_freq = 50
            for epoch in range(1, f.FLAGS.num_epochs+1):
                  sess.run(train_iter.initializer)
                  step_time = 0.0
                  fetch_time = 0.0
                  while True:
                        try:
                              a = time.time()
                              global_step += 1
                              #print(make_bread())
                              sample, label = sess.run(train_next_elem)
                              fetch_time += time.time() - a
                              a = time.time()
                              _, summ = sess.run([optimizer, train_summaries], feed_dict={x: sample, y_: label, dropout_rate: 0.5, is_training: True})
                              train_writer.add_summary(summ, global_step)
                              step_time += time.time() - a
                        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                              break

                        if global_step % display_freq == 0:
                              batch_loss, batch_accuracy = sess.run([mean_cross_entropy_loss, training_accuracy_op],
                                                                    feed_dict={x: sample, y_: label, dropout_rate: 1.0, is_training: False})
                              print ("Epoch {:3}\t Step {:5}:\t Loss={:.3f}, \tTraining Accuracy={:.5f} \tStep Time {:4.2f}m, Fetch Time {:4.2f}m".
                                     format(epoch, global_step, batch_loss, batch_accuracy, step_time/60, fetch_time/60))
                              step_time = 0.0
                              fetch_time = 0.0


                  #Validate and test after each epoch
                  val_it = validate_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
                  val_next_elem = val_it.get_next()
                  tot_tp, tot_tn, tot_fp, tot_fn = 0, 0, 0, 0
                  while True:
                        try:
                              sample, label = sess.run(val_next_elem)
                              tp, fp, tn, fn = sess.run([tp_op, fp_op, tn_op, fn_op],
                                                        feed_dict={x: sample, y_: label, dropout_rate: 1.0, is_training: False})
                        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                              break
                        tot_tp += tp
                        tot_fp += fp
                        tot_fn += fn
                        tot_tn += tn
                  precision, recall, accuracy, fscore, summ = sess.run([precision_op, recall_op, accuracy_op, fscore_op, validate_summaries],
                                                                       feed_dict={tp_sum: tot_tp, tn_sum: tot_tn, fp_sum: tot_fp, fn_sum: tot_fn})
                  validate_writer.add_summary(summ, global_step)
                  print ("Epoch %d, Step %d" % (epoch, global_step))
                  print ("="*10, "Validating Results", "="*10)
                  print ("TP: %g\nTN: %g\nFP: %g\nFN: %g" % (tot_tp, tot_tn, tot_fp, tot_fn))
                  print ("\tPrecision: %g\n\tRecall: %g\n\tF1_score: %g\n\tAccuracy: %g" % (precision, recall, fscore, accuracy))


                  test_it = test_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
                  test_next_elem = test_it.get_next()
                  tot_tp, tot_tn, tot_fp, tot_tn = 0, 0, 0, 0
                  while True:
                        try:
                              sample, label = sess.run(test_next_elem)
                              tp, fp, tn, fn, pred, lab = sess.run([tp_op, fp_op, tn_op, fn_op, logits, y_],
                                                        feed_dict={x: sample, y_: label, dropout_rate: 1.0, is_training: False})
                        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                              break
                        tot_tp += tp
                        tot_fp += fp
                        tot_fn += fn
                        tot_tn += tn
                  precision, recall, accuracy, fscore, summ = sess.run([precision_op, recall_op, accuracy_op, fscore_op, test_summaries],
                                                                       feed_dict={tp_sum: tot_tp, tn_sum: tot_tn, fp_sum: tot_fp, fn_sum: tot_fn})

                  test_writer.add_summary(summ, global_step)

                  print ("="*10, "Testing Results", "="*10)
                  print ("TP: %g\nTN: %g\nFP: %g\nFN: %g" % (tot_tp, tot_tn, tot_fp, tot_fn))
                  print ("\tPrecision: %g\n\tRecall: %g\n\tF1_score: %g\n\tAccuracy: %g" % (precision, recall, fscore, accuracy))
                  print ("="*10, "===============", "="*10)
            map_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(f.FLAGS.log_dir + "/mAP")
            map_writer.add_summary(sess.run(mAP_summ),global_step=0)
            map_writer.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
      tf.app.run()
```

Here are my results depending on the `pr_curve` command used:

```
10:06:00:26.03.2019:/media/randy/Data1/Python/Machine_Learning/3d_cnn ./run2.sh
Number of training files:  68
Number of validation files:  23
Number of testing files:  23
W0326 22:06:28.115116 139978789848896 deprecation.py:506] From /home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/slot_creator.py:187: calling Zeros.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
Saving graph to /media/randy/Data1/log/proc_order/ABS-Correlated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn_model.py", line 208, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "cnn_model.py", line 108, in main
    mAP_summ = summ_lib.pr_curve(name='mAP',predictions=logits,labels=y_,num_thresholds=11)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/pr_curve/summary.py", line 94, in op
    tf.compat.v1.assert_type(labels, tf.bool)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/check_ops.py", line 1502, in assert_type
    tf_type))
TypeError:   input/Placeholder_1:0 must be of type <dtype: 'bool'>

real    0m1.092s
user    0m1.254s
sys     0m0.751s





10:06:28:26.03.2019:/media/randy/Data1/Python/Machine_Learning/3d_cnn ./run2.sh
Number of training files:  68
Number of validation files:  23
Number of testing files:  23
W0326 22:07:04.819849 140201659422528 deprecation.py:506] From /home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/slot_creator.py:187: calling Zeros.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
Saving graph to /media/randy/Data1/log/proc_order/ABS-Correlated
2019-03-26 22:07:04.963555: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-03-26 22:07:04.966910: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1
2019-03-26 22:07:05.054544: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1010] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-03-26 22:07:05.054971: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:162] XLA service 0x4dd1b80 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-03-26 22:07:05.054985: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:169]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1070 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
2019-03-26 22:07:05.072833: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3192000000 Hz
2019-03-26 22:07:05.073556: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:162] XLA service 0x4d5bc70 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-03-26 22:07:05.073585: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:169]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-03-26 22:07:05.073788: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1464] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.683
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 7.93GiB freeMemory: 7.53GiB
2019-03-26 22:07:05.073797: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1543] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-03-26 22:07:05.073837: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened CUDA library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-03-26 22:07:05.074339: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1015] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-03-26 22:07:05.074346: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1021]      0
2019-03-26 22:07:05.074349: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1034] 0:   N
2019-03-26 22:07:05.074521: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1146] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7324 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
W0326 22:07:05.090326 140201659422528 deprecation.py:323] From cnn_model.py:122: DatasetV1.make_initializable_iterator (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `for ... in dataset:` to iterate over a dataset. If using `tf.estimator`, return the `Dataset` object directly from your input function. As a last resort, you can use `tf.compat.v1.data.make_initializable_iterator(dataset)`.
2019-03-26 22:07:06.920871: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-03-26 22:07:07.021886: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.7
Epoch   1        Step    10:     Loss=0.723,    Training Accuracy=0.75977       Step Time 0.57m, Fetch Time 0.01m
Epoch   1        Step    20:     Loss=0.528,    Training Accuracy=0.80859       Step Time 0.55m, Fetch Time 0.00m
Epoch   1        Step    30:     Loss=0.399,    Training Accuracy=0.86523       Step Time 0.55m, Fetch Time 0.00m
W0326 22:09:01.058223 140201659422528 deprecation.py:323] From cnn_model.py:157: DatasetV1.make_one_shot_iterator (from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `for ... in dataset:` to iterate over a dataset. If using `tf.estimator`, return the `Dataset` object directly from your input function. As a last resort, you can use `tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)`.
Epoch 1, Step 35
========== Validating Results ==========
TP: 980
TN: 3093
FP: 302
FN: 1257
        Precision: 0.764431
        Recall: 0.438087
        F1_score: 0.556976
        Accuracy: 0.723189
========== Testing Results ==========
TP: 1124
TN: 3500
FP: 272
FN: 2505
        Precision: 0.805158
        Recall: 0.309727
        F1_score: 0.447363
        Accuracy: 0.62478
========== =============== ==========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1320, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1408, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
         [[{{node input/Placeholder_1}}]]
         [[mAP/stack/_199]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn_model.py", line 208, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "cnn_model.py", line 204, in main
    map_writer.add_summary(sess.run(mAP_summ),global_step=0)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 930, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1153, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1329, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1349, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
         [[node input/Placeholder_1 (defined at cnn_model.py:50) ]]
         [[mAP/stack/_199]]

Original stack trace for 'input/Placeholder_1':
  File "cnn_model.py", line 208, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "cnn_model.py", line 50, in main
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2084, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6098, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 800, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3473, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/randy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1961, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()


real    1m59.745s
user    6m46.591s
sys     0m6.057s
```

Any idea on how I fix this?

In addition, if I add `print(y_)` or `print(tf.cast(y_,tf.bool))` on line 108, I get the following results:

```
Tensor("input/Placeholder_1:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Cast:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=bool)
```

which shows the tensors are of the correct size.

TF version 1.13.0-dev20190218.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  It was two different errors.  The 'bool' error was because I needed to define the map_summary on line 109 as a bool (as I did for on line 110).  The second error was due to me passing a tensor as a label instead of evaluating the tensor before passing at the end of the code.  I'll post updated code once I get it all working.